# Fill and edit List in Sharepoint online using powershell and http request

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

everyone,
I am new here and currently I am very busy with SharePoint Online and teams and Co. I would like to realize an idea and don't really know how to do that. I have found out how to bring a MessageCard via PowerShell in teams or on a SharePoint site. With incoming Webhooks this is very easy. Now I would like to change an existing card instead of creating new cards again and again. Alternatively, maybe create a list in which I can change list entries.

You probably already guessed it. I want to build a status page. From different servers I want to bring information from my Powershell scripts to a central office.

I can imagine that this is not that difficult. I just lack the right approach and after 2 days of wild googling and trying it out, I ended up here :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create a list in sharepoint, update list items with pnp powershell:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/set-pnplistitem?view=sharepoint-ps

```bsh
    Set-PnPListItem
   -List <ListPipeBind>
                  -Identity <ListItemPipeBind>
                  [-ContentType <ContentTypePipeBind>]
                  [-Values <Hashtable>]
                  [-SystemUpdate [<SwitchParameter>]]
                  [-Label <String>]
                  [-Web <WebPipeBind>]
                  [-Connection <SPOnlineConnection>]
```

or ms graph:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/listitem?view=graph-rest-1.0

```
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/items/{item-id}/fields
```

and then you could add a teams tab with the sharepoint list or create a powerapps-app

you can not delete or update channel messages with ms graph: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/chatmessage?view=graph-rest-beta